# How to execute a block of code without bypassing another one? Java

Tags: java

The title is probably not very informative. But here's the deal.

I want the user to execute a code if it's the second time he is passing there. What I did, was making a if statement, but now I've noticed, that with that, the rest isn't being executed.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
Random dice = new Random();
int counter = 1;
boolean playing = true;
boolean firstTimmer = true;
boolean got = true;

System.out.println("Welcome to numberMind! From 0 to x, you'll try to guess the random number!");
System.out.println("To quit, guess \"-1\".");
System.out.print("Insert x: ");
int x = 1+input.nextInt();
int objective = dice.nextInt(x);
System.out.print("Ok, I'm ready! What's your first guess? ");
int guess = input.nextInt();


while (playing){
    if (guess == -1){
        playing = false;
        break;
    }else if (!firstTimmer){
        got = true;
        System.out.print("Do you want to change the number range? Yes(1) No(2)");
        guess = input.nextInt();
        if (guess == 1){
            System.out.print("Insert the new x: ");
            x = 1+input.nextInt();
        }else if(guess == 2){
            System.out.println("Let's go then!");
        }else{
            System.out.print("I didn't ask for that number did I? x won't change.");
        }
    }else{
        while(got){
            if (objective == guess){
                firstTimmer = false;
                System.out.println("You guessed it in "+counter+" times!");
                counter = 1;
                System.out.print("Do you want to paly again? Yes(1) No(2) ");
                guess = input.nextInt();
                if (guess == 1){
                    System.out.println("Great! Here we go...");
                    got = false;
                    break;
                }else if (guess == 2){
                    System.out.print("Thanks for playing!");
                    got = false;
                    playing = false;
                }else{
                    System.out.println("We didn't ask for that. NOW YOU PLAY SOME MORE!");
                    got = false;
                    break;
                }
                break;
            }else if (guess == -1){
                System.out.println("You quited :(");
                break;
            }else if (guess == -2){
                System.out.println("The correct answer is "+ objective);
            }else if (counter >= 5 && (counter -5) % 3 == 0 ){
                if (objective % 2 == 0){
                    System.out.println("The number is pair.");
                }else{
            System.out.println("The number is odd.");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("You have tryed " + counter++ + " times.");
            System.out.print("What's your guess? ");
            guess = input.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```

The code I want to run is after the last else. I'm not seeing anything to solve it. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well start by asking yourself when the `else` will be fulfilled: when `guess != -1` and `firstTimmer == true`. You don't ever set `firstTimmer`, which needs to be set to true to pass through the the `else` block. You also need to remove the `break` in your `else if`, otherwise it will never reach the else on the next iteration.

Also, having both `playing = false` and `break` in your `if` statement is redundant. Both will do the same thing individually.

```
while (playing){
    if (guess == -1){
        playing = false;
        break;
    }else if (!firstTimmer){
        got = true;
        System.out.print("Do you want to change the number range? Yes(1) No(2)");
        guess = input.nextInt();
        if (guess == 1){
            System.out.print("Insert the new x: ");
            x = 1+input.nextInt();
        }else if(guess == 2){
            System.out.println("Let's go then!");
        }else{
            System.out.print("I didn't ask for that number, x won't change.");
        }
        firstTimmer = true;
        //break;
    }else{
```

Comment: Indeed! By changing that boolean I can use the code. Solved it, really wasn't thinking of that.

Comment: If your question is resolved, please click the checkmark next to my answer and mark it as resolved. This will make sure it does not show up in future searches as an unanswered question. You can also up vote my answer if you want.

Comment: Thought I had marked it already. And up voted it as well! Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

```
int counter = 0;
while(playing)  {
   counter++;      //First iteration: was zero, now 1
   if(counter == 2)  {
      //Do some special thing
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

(One) standard pattern for this sort of thing is:

```
boolean firstTime = true;
boolean playing = true;
int guess = 0;
while (playing) {
    if (guess == -1) {
        playing = false;
        // NOTE: break is redundant with playing flag, here
    } else if (!firstTime) {
        got = true;
        System.out.print("Do you want to change the number range? Yes(1) No(2)");
        guess = input.nextInt();
        if (guess == 1) {
            System.out.print("Insert the new x: ");
            x = 1+input.nextInt();
        } else if(guess == 2) {
            System.out.println("Let's go then!");
        } else {
            System.out.print("I didn't ask for that number, x won't change.");
        }
        firstTime = false;
    } else {
        //... do other work here.
    }
}
```

Also, the pattern mentioned by aliteralmind is a more flexible version of the above, allowing you to present a different option for every "visit" through the loop. I can describe further if necessary, with a complete example.

Comment: yeah, I know how to use that the counter. Thanks for the time

Answer (score 1):

You should try to solve a one problem per time in your code.

Now you have a lot of complicated code that is hard to read and work with.

The answer to your question, regarding the first time visit. Just move it before loop and then start the loop if necessary.

Try to divide the problem in sub programs (methods) and the solve them by once.

```
displayWelcomeScreen();
preapreGameContext();

do {
 if(doUserWantToChange()) {
   changeTheGameContext();
 }
 int gues = askForGues();

 hasUserGuesCorrectly();

} while(isTheGameOn());
```

The final code should look more alike the example above.